# jquery dynamic select list does not populate automatically in Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter

My limits. I can not make this to work:
I want to make a dynamic select list with jquery and JSON to populate data from database
I see it fetches data in firebug console but it does not populate the select box.
Here's my view:

```
<div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Grad</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select name="city" id="city" class="update">
                    <option value="">Odaberi</option>
                    <?php if (!empty($results)) { ?>
                    <?php foreach($results as $row) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row->city_id; ?>">
                        <?php echo $row->city_name; ?>
                    </option>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Deo grada</label>
            <div class="controls">
            <select name="category" id="category" class="update"
        disabled="disabled">
        <option value="">----</option>
    </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is my controller where i call my model:

function update_list(){
        $this->marea->update_list();

And, finally my model

```
function update_list(){
    if (!empty($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['value'])) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $value = $_GET['value'];

        try {
            $objDb = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=isport', 'root', '');
            $objDb->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

            $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM `area`
            WHERE `city_id` = ?";
            $statement = $objDb->prepare($sql);
            $statement->execute(array($value));
            $list = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if (!empty($list)) {
                $out = array('<option value="">Odaberi</option>');

                foreach($list as $row) {
                    $out[] = '<option value="'.$row['area_id'].'">'.$row['area_name'].'</option>';
                }

                echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'list' => implode('', $out)));
            } else {
                echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
            }
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
        }
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
    }
}
```

here my ajax:

```
var formObject = {
    run : function(obj) {
        if (obj.val() === '') {
            obj.nextAll('.update').html('<option value="">----</option>').attr('disabled', true);
        } else {
            var id = obj.attr('id');
            var v = obj.val();
            jQuery.getJSON(SITE +'users/update_list', { id : id, value : v }, function(data) {
                if (!data.error) {
                    obj.next('.update').html(data.list).removeAttr('disabled');
                    return;
                } else {
                    obj.nextAll('.update').html('<option value="">----</option>').attr('disabled', true);
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
$(function() {
    $('.update').live('change', function() {
        formObject.run($(this));
    });
});
```

Comment: Is your problem that the list is not populating when the page is loading or are you trying to use ajax to load the data?

Comment: i try to use ajax to load the data automaticly

Comment: You said that in firebug you can see the ajax results and they are correct? So your issue is just about getting the information into the selector?

Comment: Yes, i see Response and JSON  results

Comment: That's correct. That's the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the use of the jQuery `next` function,

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .next() method allows us to search through the immediately following sibling of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements.

Your select box is not in the same set, so the next is returning an undefined and nothing is getting updated. If you just need to use this code once for this specific spot, you can add another class or id to your second selector to specify it.

```
var formObject = {
 run : function(obj) {
    if (obj.val() === '') {
        obj.nextAll('.update').html('<option value="">----</option>').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        var id = obj.attr('id');
        var v = obj.val();
        jQuery.getJSON(SITE +'users/update_list', { id : id, value : v }, function(data) {
            if(!data.error) {
                $('#secondSelect').html(data.list).removeAttr('disabled');
            } else {
                $('#secondSelect').html('<option value="">----</option>').attr('disabled', true);
            }
        });
    }
}  };
```

Comment: thanks @GrayB, yo give me the hint and problem was solved. Next select should be following sibling element.